# Правильный синтаксис оператора Like

Tags: sql, sql-server, синтаксис

Подскажите пожалуйста синтаксис использования оператора `Like` для хранимых процедур.
Есть хранимая процедура которая вытягивает записи при условии, что в тексте (поле author) встречается слово (значение) из входного параметра.

```
Where  d.author Like '%@author%'
```

Как будет правильно?

Comment: какая БД? и укажите код как вы сами пробовали делать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server:

```
Where  d.author Like '%' + @author + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Если входной параметр называется `author`, то на Oracle условие будет выглядеть так -

```
Where  d.author Like '%'||author||'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

В Oracle вместо `LIKE` удобнее использовать `REGEXP_LIKE` - не нужно заморачиваться с процентами.

Пример:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE( d.author, 'АН')
```